# react function is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

I get the following error when trying to compile my app - 'getRestaurants' is not defined no-undef

I'm having trouble tracking down why getRestaurants is not defined for zipCodeToCoords

I have an input component that takes a zip code on submit and calls zipCodeToCoords, I then want to call getRestaurants

Here is the main react component

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      restraunts:[],
      selectedRestraunt:null
    }
  }


  getRestaurants(lat,lon){
    var url = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;
    $.ajax({
      url:url,
      headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'user_key': 'MY KEY'
      }

    }).done(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  }


  zipCodeToCoords(zip){
    var url = "https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/MYKEY/info.json/"+ zip +"/degrees";
    $.ajax({
      url:url,

    }).done(function(data){
      console.log(data.lat);
      getRestaurants(data.lat,data.lng);
    });
  }




  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="columns large-9">
            <Input onSearchTermSubmit={this.zipCodeToCoords} />
          </div>  
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="columns large-9">
            <RestrauntInfo />
          </div>
          <div className="columns large-3">
            <RestrauntList />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Input component

```
class Input extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {zip:''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }


    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSearchTermSubmit(this.state.zip);
    }
    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({zip:event.target.value});

    }

    render(){
        return(<div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="input-group">
                    <span className="input-group-label">Enter Zip Code</span>
                    <input className="input-group-field" type="number" value={this.state.zip} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <div className="input-group-button">
                      <input type="submit" className="button" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </form> 
        </div>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Get restaurants is not some global function, it is a method on your App class so you need to call it as such. The easiest way to resolve this would probably be to:

1. Change your done callback to an arrow function
2. Call `this.getRestaurants` in `zipCodeToCoords`
3. Bind `this` to `getRestaurants` and `zipCodeToCoords` in your constructor i.e. `this.getRestaurants = this.getRestaurants.bind(this);`

The callback would become:

```
done((data) => {
    console.log(data.lat);
    this.getRestaurants(data.lat,data.lng);
});
```

Comment: note that I'm assuming you're OK with using arrow functions given that you're using ES6 classes

Comment: I'm not super familiar with arrow functions What would the code look like to change the done to an arrow function

Comment: This results in the error "_this2.getRestaurants is not a function"

Comment: did you bind this to getRestaurants and zipCodeToCoords in your constructor?

Comment: Yes, " this.getRestaurants = this.getRestaurants.bind(this);"

Comment: and zipCodeToCoords?

Comment: Whoops, looks like I didn't bind zipcode. All is right in the world now. So basically the arrow function gives me access to "this"  after binding the functions in the constructor?

Comment: In this particular context, using an arrow function for the AJAX callback retains the scope of the caller inside the arrow function i.e. `this` refers to whatever it did "outside" the arrow function. Then by binding `this` to the `zipCodeToCoords` function in your constructor, it made it so `this` inside `zipCodeToCoords` refers to the App object. Good article on this http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a scoping problem, as you are passing down `zipCodeToCoords` its scope is from where it is called, not where you want. To fix this you can use .bind or if you are transpiling your app, you can change it to be an arrow function.

```
  zipCodeToCoords = (zip) => {
       ...
  }
```

You will also need to change `getRestaurants(data.lat,data.lng);` to call it from the scope, `this.getRestaurants(data.lat,data.lng);`

Comment: Calling `this.getRestaurants` inside the `done` callback won't work as `this` doesn't refer to App at this point. It requires the use of an arrow function for the callback, explicitly binding `this` to the call back, or creating a reference to this outside the callback that is then used in the callback

Comment: Didn't see the callback in there, yes you are correct!